# Asynchronous image loading from url to populate listview

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm currently experiencing a little trouble with async image loading to populate "infinite" list view(loading data from url and storing in custom adapter). I found [this](https://github.com/Redth/MonoDroid.UrlImageViewHelper) extension methods to ImageView, which basically is port to [koush/UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper), but the original was updated a lot, and the port is not being updated for 9 moths now... When I'm populating ImageView in my custom adapter, everything is seems to work fine and fast (I'm downloading small images from pretty fast server), but after approximately 200 images (each 15-20 kb in size) the downloading is stopping. I assume that the problem is in the images caching, but even by using the "Cleanup" method provided in the extension, nothing is changing. Does anyone knows how to fix that, or have better solution to that task? I've tried to create my own "Queue", but it has another sort of problem - when scrolling the listview, any new ImageView already have source image, that changing to the correct one, but with fast scrolling this is looking very bad.
Here is my code:

### GetView in my custom list adapter

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    //Populating the adapter with new items
    if (position >= this._items.Count - 1)
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => this.LoadPage());

    var item = this._items[position];
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null)
        view = this._context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomRowView, null);

    var imgUrl = string.Format(@"http://myserver.com/?action={0}&url={1}", "get.thumbnail", item.Image.Url);

    //Here is the image loading row
    view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1).SetUrlDrawable(imgUrl);

    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtTitle).Text = item.Title;
    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtYear).Text = item.Information.Year;
    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtGenre).Text = item.Information.Genre;
    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtGrade).Text = item.Rating.Grade;
    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtVotes).Text = string.Format("( {0} )", item.Rating.Votes);

    return view;
}
```

### LoadPage function

```
public void LoadPage()
{
    OnUpdateAnimeListStart(); //Event to display loading message
    try
    {
        this._items.FillListFromUrl(string.Format("http://myserver.com/page/{0}/", this._page));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        _context.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(_context)
                .SetPositiveButton("Ok", (sender, args) =>
                {
                    Intent blankIntent = new Intent();
                    blankIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                    int intPID = Android.OS.Process.MyPid();
                    Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(intPID);
                })
                .SetMessage(ex.Message)
                .SetTitle("Error!")
                .Show();
        });
    }

    this._page++;
    _context.RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        _context.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView).InvalidateViews();
    });

    OnUpdateAnimeListEnd(); //Event to hide loading message
}
```

---

### And this is my alternative "Queue", that I talked about

```
    public class ImageDownloader
    {
        private List<ImageView> _queueImageViews;
        private List<string> _queueImageUrls;
        private Activity _context;

        public ImageDownloader(Activity context)
        {
            this._context = context;
            this._queueImageViews = new List<ImageView>();
            this._queueImageUrls = new List<string>();
        }

        public void DownloadImage(ImageView imgView, string url)
        {
            this._queueImageViews.Add(imgView);
            this._queueImageUrls.Add(url);

            if (this._queueImageViews.Count == 1)
                this._startJob();
        }

        private void _startJob()
        {
            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            web.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(web_DownloadDataCompleted);
            web.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(this._queueImageUrls[0]));
        }

        private void _removeFromeQueue(int index = 0)
        {
            this._queueImageUrls.Remove(this._queueImageUrls[index]);
            this._queueImageViews.Remove(this._queueImageViews[index]);

        }

        void web_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageView v = this._queueImageViews[0];
            this._context.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(e.Result, 0, e.Result.Length);
                v.SetImageBitmap(bm);
            });
            this._removeFromeQueue();
            if (this._queueImageViews.Count > 0)
                this._startJob();
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but you may consider using this loader instead because it is from official Android developer blog. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html

Comment: I'll take a look in it, and may be will try to port this to monodroid, but I bet, that other monodroid developers already found the solution to this kind of problem, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel. But if there is no other choice - then there is no other choice :)

Comment: I did not want to sidetrack you, only was curious why you assume that the problem is in the images caching?  Is it possible that the code that downloads images is not closing network connections?

Comment: @Y2i, first of all - thank you! In the UrlImageViewHelper port, the creator actually forgot to close connection. I fixed that, but unfortunately this still not solved my problem :( I think the problem is in this methods cache, because of the undefined exceptions in cache sections. But may be this is not the source of the problem...

Comment: Try volley library by Google. https://developers.google.com/live/shows/474338138 . It can load images and populate listView efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem, thanks to a little bit more debugging in the UrlImageViewHelper port.
As I assumed, the problem was in the caching. The logic behind was to limit cached items to specific number (I don't know why, but it was hardcoded), and if the limit is reached, then need to remove first few items from cache. This is fine, but the implementation still have some bugs. For now, instead of debug more, and fix the implementation, I increased the limit to 5000 (originally it was set to 100), but this is only the temporary way to fix this. In future I'll probably will fix the code, so it will delete first items in cache collection. So here it is:

### `SoftReferenceHashTable<TKey, TValue>` class

Fixed this line:
`LRUCache<TKey, TValue> cache = new LRUCache<TKey, TValue>(100);` 
To this:
`LRUCache<TKey, TValue> cache = new LRUCache<TKey, TValue>(5000);`

---

Additionally, thanks to **@Y2i**'s comment, I found that in `UrlImageViewHelper` class, in the `SetUrlDrawable` method the downloading was implemented without closing the internet connection. May be this wasn't so much a problem, but I prefer to fix that. So I changed this part of a code:

```
var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
var data = client.DownloadData(url);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, data);
return LoadDrawableFromFile(context, filename);
```

To this:

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    var data = client.DownloadData(url);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, data);
    return LoadDrawableFromFile(context, filename);
}
```

Comment: Not closing connections has similar symptoms (all downloads suddenly stop) when connection pooling is used, but it looks like WebClient does not use connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question and this is what I came up with for my answer. The Monodroid version of koush/UrlImageViewHelper gave me problems as well. So i pulled it apart rebuilt my own version. Hopefully someone will find this useful.

http://xandroid4net.blogspot.com/2014/09/xamarinandroid-loading-images-from-web.html